# How to use ssh_import_id with cloud-init on Raspberry Pi 4 /w Ubuntu 20.04 Server?

Tags: server, raspberrypi, cloud-init

I'm looking to automatically setup up my SSH keys on a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04 install on a Raspberry Pi 4 - mostly as a learning exercise. I'm trying to use the `ssh_import_id` option of [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#users-and-groups) to pull my SSH public key from my GitHub account and add it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the `pi` user.

I cannot seem to get the `ssh_import_id` config to kick in. The `~/.ssh` directory is never made for the `pi` user, and there are no logs relating to anything to do with pulling a key from GitHub/ssh_import_id in `/var/logs/cloud-init.log` or `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

The current contents of my `user-data`on the root of the SD card:

```
  - name: pi
    groups: [sudo]
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_import_id: # import public key from github
      - gh:my_cool_github_account
    lock_passwd: true # disable password login
```

Everything works fine if I input the public key manually using `ssh_authorized_keys`, which will suit my workflow but I'm hoping to get the GitHub thing setup as it's snazzy.

My understanding of `cloud-init` is definitely a little basic, so I may have missed something. I'm triggering changes by running `cloud-init clean` and then `cloud-init init`, which feels like it's running fine as it's remaking users/general bits/the root ssh keys and fingerprint.

I'm presumably also using the `NoCloud` datasource.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Is that only a snippet of your user data? If not, you also need the `#cloud-config` header and `users:`. Something like this should work:

```yaml
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: pi
    groups: [sudo]
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_import_id:
      - gh:torvalds
    lock_passwd: true
```

I just tested and found the key in `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You're sure the github user you're trying to import has keys located at `https://github.com/settings/keys`?

`/var/log/cloud-init.log` contains:

```
2021-08-09 13:56:24,302 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-ssh-import-id using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/instances/me/sem/config_ssh_import_id'>)
2021-08-09 13:56:24,302 - cc_ssh_import_id.py[DEBUG]: Importing SSH ids for user pi.
2021-08-09 13:56:24,302 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['sudo', '-Hu', 'pi', 'ssh-import-id', 'gh:torvalds'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to cloud-init's docs `ssh_import_id` module is only available for Ubuntu and Debian, however depending on the flavour and version of Ubuntu/Debian, the `ssh-import-id` binary that cloud-init's `ssh_import_id` module uses behind the scenes to actually retreive the keys, might or might not be installed on your distro.

For example, https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bullseye/latest/debian-11-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2 did not come with it, and therefore cloud-init failed to import my keys from Github. In my case I saw a clear `command not found` error in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

Check if `ssh-import-id` command was present in your initialized system. If it was not not there, then you might want to try adding this block to your `user-data`:

```yml
packages:
  - ssh-import-id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
users:
  - name: pi
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa <your key here>
```

That should put your key in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the `pi` user